# Get `ICredentials` from Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm using Windows Authentication.

I need to log into a service. It requires authentication using an `ICredentials` object, but would rather avoid asking for the user to enter their credentials again.

Is there a way to get the `ICredentials` from the currently logged in user?

The service is the TFS SDK.

Comment: What kind of service? What kind of authentication protocol?

Comment: The service requires an `ICredentials` to authenticate. clarified question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Controller in MVC has a property `User` which is `IPrincipal`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

`IPrincipal` has an `Identity` property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.identity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

which is of type `IIdentity`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you're using Windows Authentication the actual instance will be of type `WindowsIdentity`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hopefully it will contain all the credential information you need.

Also, you might want to try:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
```

Comment: `ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;` was what I was looking for.